# Why Jquery Datetime picker is lost after postback?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jquerydatetimepicker

I have used Jquery DateTime Picker. It works fine at first page load but stop working after postback or any button click. why ? I don't understand why ?

in head:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#<%= txtBoxDateOfBirth.ClientID %>").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

in pageload of asp.net:

```
StringBuilder scripts = new StringBuilder();
scripts.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>");
scripts.Append("$(function () {");
scripts.Append("$('txtBoxDateOfBirth')");
scripts.Append("});");
scripts.Append("</script>)");

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), txtBoxDateOfBirth.ClientID + "_ReadyScript", scripts.ToString());
```

but still it stops working upon any button click or postback, why ?

Answer (score 0):

Is `txtBoxDateOfBirth` placed inside an UpdatePanel ? if it is, the javascript needs to be registered everytime the panel is updated.

What is the point of the js in the app code ? You just wrap the `txtBoxDateOfBirth` in a jQuery object and do nothing with it.

Side note : [Page.RegisterStartupScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript(v=vs.110).aspx) is depracted, you should use [ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write your page load code like this(not in postback condision):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder scripts = new StringBuilder();
        scripts.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>");
        scripts.Append("$(function () {");
        scripts.Append("$('txtBoxDateOfBirth').datepicker();");
        scripts.Append("});");
        scripts.Append("</script>)");

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), txtBoxDateOfBirth.ClientID + "_ReadyScript", scripts.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use in page Load IsPostBack method and place your code inside if condition

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
 {
    ...  ...  .. 
 }
```